# looking for way/compoments to read/edit true MS excel 2007 files

Tags: delphi, excel-2007

Im looking for guide(OLE/ADO) or ready native components to read/edit/write MS excel 2007 files.

so far iv tried Native excel ver2 and txlsfile ver 4 , XLSReadWriteII ver 4 but seems native excel can't open excel 2007 .

txlsfile or XLSReadWriteII (sorry i removed them and can't remember which one was ) can open/read but when edit and save it produced only 4kb corrupted xlsx file .

Answer (score 4):

for use ADO to connect a Excel 2007 file you can use a connection string like this

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data
>   Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended
>   Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";

this connection string uses the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider wich you can download from [`(2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components)`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en).

try this code wich shown how connect to a excel 2007 file using ADO.

```
const
ExcelStr='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";';

procedure TForm1.ButtonOpen(Sender: TObject);
begin
 try
   ADOConnection1.ConnectionString:=Format(ExcelStr,['C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\My Dropbox\excelfile2007.xlsx']); // set the name of your excel file
   ADOConnection1.Connected:=True; //connect to the excel file
   ADODataSet1.CommandText:='Select * from [Sheet1$]';//create your sql query
   ADODataSet1.Open; //open the excel file
    while not ADODataSet1.eof do 
    begin
      //do your job here. 
      //ADODataSet1.FieldByName('Field1').AsString



     ADODataSet1.Next;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
      ShowMessage(Format('%s Error %s',[E.Classname, E.Message]));
 end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of components I've used in the past has been [EMS Advanced Data Import/Export](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products#tools).

They've always just worked for my needs.